# Free algebra generated by one element, but has two unary operations

Tags: abstract-algebra, universal-algebra

My question is - how can I describe a free Algebra, say $\mathcal F_{\mathcal K}(1)$, where $\mathcal K$ is a class of all algebras that have two unary operations - they are arbitrary and not specifically defined.

The notation $\mathcal F_{\mathcal K}(1)$ is meant to describe that this algebra is generated by one element and belongs to the class $\mathcal K$. My textbook says that a free monoid generated by two elements can be used to obtain an algebra such as $\mathcal F_{\mathcal K}(1)$ - unfortunately that was only a remark, with no further explanation.

I would appreciate any kind of an example for a free algebra that fulfills these properties.

Comment: What are the unary operations? Which properties do we need for them? The notation $\mathcal F_{\mathcal K}(1)$ has no point to comprehend it. Please give references, examples...

Comment: I edited the question, thanks.

Comment: A free algebra generated by one element over some ring $R$, e.g. $R=\Bbb Z$, say, is commutative, and isomorphic with $R[x]$, the polynomial ring over $R$. Now we can put on this algebra two trivial unary operations, $x\to x$. Without any further information we cannot figure out where is the problem...

Comment: Thanks again, I just fixed the question again. What I wanted to know is how can I describe these algebras, and in how can a free monoid generated by two elements have anything to do with algebras with one element and unary operations.

Comment: @dan_fulea This is using "algebra" in the sense of **universal algebra**, not ring theory.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call our two unary operations $f$ and $g$ and our generator $\alpha$. Elements of the free algebra correspond to exactly **finite binary sequences**: interpret $0$ as $f$ and $1$ as $g$. For example, the element $$f(g(g(f(f(\alpha)))))$$ corresponds to the sequence $$01100.$$ By freeness, no two distinct binary sequences correspond to different elements of the algebra, so this really is a one-to-one correspondence.

Now the finite binary strings (including the empty string, which corresponds to $\alpha$ itself) actually carries some structure of its own: it is the **free monoid on two generators**. The two generators are $0$ and $1$, and the monoid operation is concatenation.

(In my opinion, this is really more connected to the set of *term functions* on our original algebra rather than that algebra itself: e.g. $010$ corresponds to the term $f(g(f(x)))$, and the empty string corresponds to the term $x$; elements of the algebra itself are the values of these term functions on the generator $\alpha$.)